# Searching for blocks of integers in file ending with the same pattern

Tags: c, scanf

so I'm trying to search through a file for a sequence of float-numbers. the end sequence is `0.0` for each block.

I want to be able to select the piece of numbers and treat them as individual strings so to speak. As you can see, it's quite convenient to always being able to chose `0.0` as your end-limit of your selection range, but thus far i haven't been able to accomplish this. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

current code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
  #define TRUE 1 //for convenience later on
  #define FALSE 0
  #define CHUNK 1024 /* read 1024 bytes at a time, will be used later*/ 
  char buf[CHUNK];
  long *n;
  n=NULL;
  FILE *in_file = fopen("Measurements.txt","r");

  if(in_file == NULL){ //test for files not executing again.
    printf("File could not be read/found...");
    exit(1);
  }
  //searching for end of string-block
  fscanf(in_file,"%[^0.0];",n);
  puts(&n); // trying to see if the fscanf function actually selected the right numbers

  if(in_file){
    fclose(in_file);
  }
```

Chunk of code in the Measurement.txt file:

```
210.5    210.9    213.8    209.3    214.7    214.2    214.4    211.8
213.9    213.6    214.5    214.3    213.2    215.5    210.9    212.3
215.4    212.4    210.6    210.4    216.2    209.9    211.4    213.7
213.9    209.2    210.4    211.8    215.8    216.4    216.1    209.6
217.5    209.8    210.8    216.4    209.4    217.0    212.3    217.7
216.5    214.4    217.2    215.5    217.6    211.6    211.8    213.7
217.0    211.3    217.2    211.2    210.2    215.1    217.2    211.9
216.8    217.5    212.1    217.5    212.9    217.2    211.0    215.2
216.8    211.6    210.9    216.4    210.8    213.0    210.9    217.2
217.3    216.2    213.4    209.2    215.9    212.1    210.5    211.3
215.5    212.7    216.6    214.2    215.9    209.4    212.1    217.6
213.2    213.5    217.6    214.6    211.1    209.6    213.6    213.7
209.2    210.4    214.7    215.0    0.0
```

This pattern is repeated 4-5 times (but should be treated as it could occur an arbitrary amount of times, ofc with different values but always ending with `0.0`).

Comment: First off you should put all your `#define` at the top outside main right underneath all your `#include`

Comment: @JackWilliams it's actually a void function which is called in another function which is a part of a bigger program, so no. just modified it for your convenience.

Comment: @JackWilliams: That's a pure style choice, and has no bearing on correctness of the program.

Comment: Is this code complete?  `long *n; n = NULL;` with no memory allocated to `n` before `fscanf(in_file,"%[^0.0];",n);` and then `puts(&n);`?  Dereferencing a `NULL` pointer?  And then, assuming `NULL` is a numeric zero, printing a zero-length string?

Comment: Should `0.00` end the block?  How about `-0.0`?  or just text `0.0`?

Answer (score 3):

This:

```
fscanf(in_file,"%[^0.0];",n);
```

Does not do what you think it does.  In particular, the format `%[^0.0];` does not select "numbers other than 0.0."  You should keep it simple:

```
double num;
while (fscanf(in_file, "%f", &num) == 1) {
  if (num == 0.0) {
    // we are at the end of a block
  }
}
```

Note that I also used `double` instead of `long` because you have floating-point inputs.

Answer (score 1):

I'd try something that starts out like this, assuming the file fits in memory and contains nothing but text (no NUL characters), numbers are separated by space characters, and that the only numbers that match `0.0` signify the end of a block of numbers:

```
void addToBlock( double num )
{
    // add a value to a block of numbers
    // use a global array or similar data structure
}

processBlock()
{
    // process a block of numbers
    // and then reset it to start over
}

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    // read entire contents into memory (could also just mmap
    // the file but that doesn't guarantee you can treat the
    // contents as a NUL-terminated string
    struct stat sb;
    int fd = open( argv[ 1 ], O_RDONLY );
    fstat( fd, &sb );
    char *content = malloc( sb.st_size + 1 );
    read( fd, content, sb.st_size );
    close( fd );

    // NUL-terminate our data so it's a string
    content[ sb.st_size ] = '\0';

    // start at the beginning, convert each number we find
    // into a double, loop until the conversion fails
    char *current = content;
    for ( ;; )
    {
        char *last;
        double num = strtod( current, &last );

        // if last == current, the conversion failed so
        // break the loop
        if ( current == last )
        {
            break;
        }

        // match your pattern here - keep a circular buffer or
        // an array
        if ( 0.0 == num )
        {
            processBlock();
        }
        else
        {
            addToBlock( num );
        }

        // skip to the next number
        current = last;
    }
    free( content );
    return( 0 );
}
```

You'd need to add some more error checking there, especially for the `read()` call.